# Can't connect to one wifi network, keeps asking for password

Tags: wireless, networking, 14.04, iwlwifi

Here's the relevant syslog stuff: http://pastie.org/9405812

Here's the output from the wireless-info script: http://paste.ubuntu.com/7821949/

My wifi works well in general, I only have problems with this network. The router is a netgear wnr1000v2-vc. It may be possessed.

Things I've tried: Disabling power management, reboot, satanic ritual, rebooting a second time, giving up, deciding not to give up after all, posting on ask ubuntu

Comment: What is the network you can not connect too?

Comment: Talia-PC_network

Answer (score 1):

First remove all special characters from the network name.

Now, check the settings in the router. WPA2-AES is preferred; not WPA and WPA2 mixed mode and certainly not TKIP. Second, if your router is capable of N speeds, I have better luck with a channel width of 20 MHz in the 2.4 GHz band instead of automatic 20/40 MHz.

I also have better luck with a fixed channel, either 1, or 11, rather than automatic channel selection. After making these changes, reboot the router.

Next, I recommend that your regulatory domain be set explicitly. Check yours:

```
sudo iw reg get
```

If you get 00, that is a one-size-fits-all setting. Find yours here: [Country Code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1_alpha-2) Then set it temporarily:

```
sudo iw reg set IS
```

Of course, substitute your country code if not Iceland. Set it permanently:

```
gksudo gedit /etc/default/crda
```

Use nano or kate or leafpad if you don't have the text editor gedit.

Change the last line to read:

```
REGDOMAIN=IS
```

Proofread carefully, save and close the text editor.

Next, I'd set IPv6 to Ignore in Network Manager: [IPV6 setting](http://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora/18/html/Installation_Guide/images/netconfig/network-connections-ipv6-ignore.png)  This example is for ethernet, but you want wireless.

Answer (score 0):

Try delete that wifi connection from the **Network Connections** list (wifi icon).

Then restart wireless with `sudo service network-manager restart`

Comment: I tried, it didn't work.

Comment: After deleting that connection. Reboot. And then try connecting to that connection again. I had to reboot last time in order for it to work.

Answer (score 0):

add this option in kernel drivers settings

```
echo options iwlwifi 11n_disable=1 | tee -a /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf
```

Then restart the system this must fix wifi problem.